# Multithreaded deduplication of sets

Tags: algorithms

Let's say there are four sets containing integers. No set has any duplicates within itself, but duplicates exist across sets.

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
B = [2, 3, 4, 5]
C = [3, 4, 5, 6]
D = [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

The goal is to store each unique element in a resulting set `R`. The naïve single-threaded solution would be to iterate over each set one after the other while keeping track of already seen elements in a separate data structure `S`. If an element was already seen, do nothing. Otherwise, store the element in `R` and update `S`.

For large sets (e.g. 10,000,000 or more total elements) this can get quite slow. Is there a multi-threaded approach for this problem which improves performance?

Comment: Ten milllion elements is not so large and "quite slow" is dubious (will run below a second).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that each set is stored as a sorted list/array.  You can compute the union of two sets using a [merge algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm).  This should run in linear time, and is quite I/O friendly, as you only scan through the list in a forward direction (no random access needed).  It is easy to extend this to a four-way merge.

If you have $N$ processors, one approach is to divide the range of integers into $N$ subranges, and have each processor responsible for the portion that falls within that range.  In other words, suppose that all integers are in the range $[0,M-1]$.  Then the $i$th processor can be assigned the range $[(i-1)M/N,iM/N-1]$.  The $i$th processor is responsible for computing

$$(A \cap [(i-1)M/N,iM/N-1]) \cup \cdots \cup (D \cap [(i-1)M/N,iM/N-1]).$$

It can do this by using binary search to find the first and last element of A in this range, and the same for each of B, C, D, and then running a four-way merge on the elements of A,B,C,D in that range.

Finally, you concatenate the outputs of all $N$ processors.

Comment: Interesting approach. Anyway you are betting on the fact that the elements are fairly uniformly spread by range. If this is not the case, the workloads can be completely imbalanced (to the point that only one thread will run). Better perform efficient selection of the $\frac{kN}{P}^{\text{th}}$ elements (array of length $N$, $P$ threads).

Comment: @YvesDaoust, good point, that's a nice idea!